# Two columns ( 3 and 9 ) don't line up

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

This is my template file from Angular:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col bg-dark text-white">
        <a class="navbar-brand">SPORTS STORE</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-white">
      <div class="col-3 bg-info p-2">
        {{categories.length}} Categories
      </div>
      <div class="col-9 bg-success p-2">
        {{products.length}} Products
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So in the second one, so we have one row and two columns of 3 and 9 in that row.
My question is why they are breaking in two lines?

[image]

Comment: It is working fine with your code https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-yonath-w10ld?file=/src/index.js  . Please check again.

Comment: For me it works as well: https://www.codeply.com/p/wmf9ENQbNp also, try adding `margin: 0;` to body